# Access Variables from within function using Globals

Tags: matlab

I want to access variables from within a function using globals

```
Global x y z
Answer = MyFunction(4)
y



Function Result = MyFunction(x)
y=x+1;
z=y+1;
```

I would like to be able to access the value of y from the last time I call the function.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following function on the MATLAB search path:

```
function z = myFunction(x)
global y
fprintf('in myFunction -> y = %f\n', y);
y=x+1;
z=y+1;
end
```

Call `myFunction` from a script or command line.

```
global y;
y = 0;
answer = myFunction(3);
fprintf('past myFunction -> answer = %f\n', answer);
fprintf('past myFunction -> y = %f\n', y);
```

Since handle classes have been introduced to the MATLAB object model, I suggest not using *globals*.

Comment: Persistent variables can also be a good alternative to a global, depending on what you are trying to do. I agree that the use of globals should be avoided whenever possible (which is most of the time),